# Show no result found pop-up in angular 6 search filter

Tags: angular

I am using a ng2-search-filter in angular6. I want when some result is not found then a popup or alert should come which should say no result found.

I am using the third party package ng2-search-filter

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter

Comment: and your code is ?

Comment: Please provide code if you want our help also tell us what have you tried so far.

Comment: are you using angular materal or bootstrap?

Comment: I am using ng2-search-filter plugin. Link of code is there in the question.